# How to stub a module function with Cypress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress, sinon, okta-api

I want to create a test with Cypress that has a React component that uses an auth library (`@okta/okta-react`) with a HOC (`withOktaAuth`).

My component looks like this:

```js
// Welcome.js

import { withOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react'

const Welcome = ({authState}) => {
  return <div>{authState.isAuthenticated ? 'stubbed' : 'not working'}</div>
}

export default withOktaAuth(Welcome)
```

I tried to make a test like so:

```js
// test.js

import * as OktaReact from '@okta/okta-react'

const withOktaAuthStub = Component => {
  Component.defaultProps = {
    ...Component.defaultProps,
    authState: {
      isAuthenticated: true,
      isPending: false
    },
    authService: {
      accessToken: '123'
    }
  }

  return Component
}

describe('Test auth', () => {
  before(() => {
    cy.stub(OktaReact, 'withOktaAuth').callsFake(withOktaAuthStub)
  })

  it('Stubs auth', () => {
    cy.visit('/welcome')
    cy.contains('stubbed')
  })
})
```

When I run the test, the component still does not use the stubbed function. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Were you able to find the solution to this problem?

Comment: I am observing the same problem and I am in a codebase that has stubs that work like expected in 6.5.0 but upgrading to 7.3.0 they fail.

Answer (score 1):

It's been 2 years that this questions was submitted, but for those who still encounters that error, Cypress provides a guide about Okta e2e testing: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/okta-authentication#Adapting-the-back-end